# Rails Functional Test of Arbitrary or Custom URLs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, controller, functional-testing

I have a RESTful resource in my Rails app called "Photo". I'm using [Paperclip](http://www.thoughtbot.com/projects/paperclip) to serve different "styles" of my photos (for thumbnails and the like), and I'm using a custom route to RESTfully access those styles:

```
map.connect "photos/:id/style/*style", :controller => "photos", :action => "show"
```

That's working fine, but I want to write a test to make sure it stays that way.

I already have a functional test to call the Photo controller's show action (generated by scaffold in fact):

```
test "should show photo" do
  get :show, :id => photos(:one).to_param
  assert_response :success
end
```

That tests the execution of the action at the URL "/photo/1". Now I want to test the execution of the URL "/photo/1/style/foo". Unfortunately, I can't seem to get ActionController::TestCase to hit that URL; the get method always wants an action/id and won't accept a URL suffix.

How do I go about testing a custom URL?

### Update

While checking on @fernyb's answer I found this snippet in [the same rdoc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Routing.html)

> In tests you can simply pass the URL or named route to get or post. 
>       def send_to_jail
>         get '/jail'
>         assert_response :success
>         assert_template "jail/front"
>       end

However, when I actually *try* that, I get an error message:

```
test "should get photo" do
  get "/photos/1/style/original"
  assert_equal( "image/jpeg", @response.content_type )
end  

ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches {:action=>"/photos/1/style/original", :controller=>"photos"}
```

I wonder if I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `assert_routing` to test routes:

```
assert_routing("/photos/10/style", :controller => "photos", :action => "show", :id => "10", :style => [])

assert_routing("/photos/10/style/cool", :controller => "photos", :action => "show", :id => "10", :style => ["cool"])

assert_routing("/photos/10/style/cool/and/awesome", :controller => "photos", :action => "show", :id => "10", :style => ["cool", "and", "awesome"])
```

In your **integration test** you can then do:

```
test "get photos" do
   get "/photos/10/style/cool"
   assert_response :success
end
```

Comment: That's useful stuff, but it doesn't actually call the action; it just checks that the routing of the URLs will result in the particular action/params. (I'll edit my question to clarify what I'm looking for).

Answer (score 1):

[From the Rails API documentation:](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Routing.html)

> **Route globbing**
>
> Specifying `*[string]` as part of a
>   rule like:
>
> ```
> map.connect '*path' , :controller => 'blog' , :action => 'unrecognized?'
> ```
>
> will glob all remaining parts of the
>   route that were not recognized
>   earlier. The globbed values are in
>   `params[:path]` as an array of path
>   segments.

So it looks like you need to pass the `:path` arguments, to test the action correctly.

Comment: I had thought about that, but I was really hoping to avoid it. The actual use case is the URL being in a certain format; passing in the path segments as a parameter bypasses that check.

Comment: Are you trying to test the framework? When you `get /photos/1/styles/foo', it's up to Rails to parse the URL and call the controller. You shouldn't need to worry about that, just pass the expected parameters to the action that Rails will call it with.